# substituir goto por laço

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um menu de opções, com opção de input 1 ou 0 e quero que apareça um erro quando não digitado 1 ou 0, e assim sucessivamente até que o usuário escolha uma opção válida e assim o programa redireciona o usuário para a tela escolhida, eu consegui estruturar o código usando goto, no entanto eu gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma de usar algum laço ao invés do `goto`, não consegui e me restou apenas o `goto`.

```
void main()
    {

            int p1, s2, s3;

            system("clear");
            printf("Digite:\n[1] Para acessar o menu\n[0] Para sair do programa\n\n>>> ");
            scanf("%i", &p1);

            switch (p1)
            {       

                    case 0:
                    exit:   
                    system("clear");
                    printf("Saindo\n\n");
                    break;  

                    //Pagina do Menu
                    case 1: 
                    menu:   
                    system("clear");
                    printf("Menu\n\n");
                    break;  

                    default:
                    do{     
                            system("clear");
                            printf("Comando invalido!\n\nDigite:\n[1] Para acessar o menu\n[0] Para sair do programa\n\n>>> ");
                            scanf("%i", &p1);
                    }while (p1!=0 && p1!=1); 

                    if (p1==0){
                            goto exit;
                    }
                    if (p1==1) {
                            goto menu;
                    }

            }
    }
```

Comment: Dê um lida [Edsger W. Dijkstra: Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

Answer (score 2):

O uso de `goto` é uma péssima ideia. Basta utilizar um laço de repetição.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int p1, s2, s3;
    do {
        system("clear");
        printf("Digite:\n[1] Para acessar o menu\n[0] Para sair do programa\n\n>>> ");
        scanf("%i", &p1);
        switch (p1)
        {       
            case 0:
                system("clear");
                printf("Saindo\n\n");
                break;  
            //Pagina do Menu
            case 1: 
                system("clear");
                printf("Menu\n\n");
                break;  
            default:
                printf("Comando invalido!\n");
        }
    } while (p1 != 0);
    return 0;
}
```